# How do i add a working dropdown list to my laravel registration form?

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, homestead

Im trying to add a dropdown list on my registration form in laravel so that a user can select what type of functionality they have. for example there will be two options one being a student where they can only edit/delete their own content once logged in and one being Admin where the admin can edit/delete all content.

At the moment i have managed to add the dropdown list to the form and it is appearing in the form but when i click on register i get an error message saying the 'role' field is required even though i have selected a role:

like this:

the Role field was selected, it deselects when the error pops up.
[image]

This is my code within my registration.blade.php file:

```
<div class="form-group row">    
     <label for="role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Role') }}</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
              <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role_selected" required focus>
                  <option value="Admin"  selected>Admin</option>        
                  <option value="Student"  selected>Student</option>        
                  <option value="Select Role" disabled selected>Select Role</option>        
              </select>
         </div>
</div>
```

And when i make the role field so that is not a required field i get this error:

```
Undefined index: role
```

and this is my code in my registerController and user table:

RegisterController.php:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'role',

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]);
}
}
```

My create users table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('role');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

Is there something that i have forgotten to add in my html file because im not sure why its not working?

Comment: Side note: Allowing users to select whether they want control as an admin, is not a wise decision with regards to design. Any user can select the role of an admin and then have greater access/control than desired - think about it

Comment: I know i am mainly just trying to get the drop down list to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in blade file

```
<div class="form-group row">    
 <label for="role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Role') }}</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" required focus>
              <option value="Admin">Admin</option>        
              <option value="Student">Student</option>        
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Role</option>        
          </select>
     </div>
```

> Controller

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    'role' => ['required', 'string'],

]);
}
```

Try this may be it's work

Comment: im now getting this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, i just added 'role' to the protected fillables in the user.php file

Answer (score 2):

In your `select` tag code you have given your `select` the `name` of `role_selected` this is the reason of the error as you are validating `role` in form validation.
Use the following code to fix it:

```
<select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" required focus>
              <option value="Admin"  selected>Admin</option>        
              <option value="Student"  selected>Student</option>        
              <option value="Select Role" disabled selected>Select Role</option>        
          </select>
```